# How to read 2 or more records in Hive UDF?

Tags: hive

I have a table of some toll stations logs. My task, "translated" into SQL is:

step 1. sort these records, using GROUP BY station, lane.

step 2. arrange these records, using ORDER BY check_time.

step 3.**[that is the problem]** consecutively judge every two contiguous records in each group, whether the interval is less then 5 seconds or not.

It is easy if I can do it in C, Java or others but not in SQL.
It seems that Hive UDF(User Defined Function) can help me do that. I have read the Demo UDF from official documentaion. But still I don't know how to pass the consecutive 2 records into my function. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using SQL. 
Using `LAG()` [analytic function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) you can get previous row `check_time` and other columns if necessary. Then do a calculation with two timestamps. Convert timestamps to seconds using unix_timestamp() and subtract:

```
select t.*, 
       case when time_diff < 5 then ... else ... end --do some logic
from
(
select t.*,
       --current time minus previous time
       unix_timestamp(check_time) -
       unix_timestamp(lag(check_time) over (partition by station, lane order by check_time)) as time_diff
  from table t
) t
```

The `Lead()` analytic function to get next row's check_time or other column if necessary.